# Inequality in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I'm stuck in the proof of the following inequality for an arbitrary $z\in \mathbb{C}$:

$$
\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert \leq \frac{C}{\left\vert z\right\vert 
},\text{ for large }\left\vert z\right\vert ,
$$

where $a\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}$ and assume that $\Re(z)$ is bounded.

If we multiply $\sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z$ by its conjugate we find
$$
\sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z=\frac{a}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}+z}.
$$

If $\Re(z)\geq 0,$ we know that $\sqrt{z^{2}+a}=\sqrt{z^{2}}\sqrt{%
z^{2}+a}=z\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{z^{2}}},$ therefore
$$
\left\vert \frac{a}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}+z}\right\vert \leq \left\vert \frac{1}{z}%
\right\vert \frac{1}{\left\vert \sqrt{1-\left\vert \frac{a}{z^{2}}%
\right\vert }+1\right\vert }\leq \frac{C}{\left\vert z\right\vert }\text{ 
for large }\left\vert z\right\vert .
$$

Now, if $\Re(z)\leq 0$ we have $\sqrt{z^{2}+a}=\sqrt{z^{2}}\sqrt{%
z^{2}+a}=-z\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{z^{2}}}$ and so
$$
\sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z=-z\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{z^{2}}}-z.
$$

The above approach doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas?.

Thank you.

Comment: Define $\sqrt {z^{2}+a}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if $a$ is positive, this function is defined on the branch $\mathbb{C} - [-ai,ai] $, if $a$ is negative then it is defined on the branch $\mathbb{C} - [-a,ai]$.     I have added the assumption that $\Re(z)$ is bounded.

Comment: Your first line is pretty close. It already looks like $  C  / |z| $. so can you force it into that form?

Comment: @CalvinLin for $\Re(z)$ positive I think that it is true?. Did you find my proof incorrect?

Comment: Personally speaking, your proof isn't the "right" to think about this, so I didn't check the details.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find a large enough $ n$, so that for $ |z| > n$, (say)

$$ |z| \leq \left| \sqrt{ z^2 + a }  + z \right|.$$

**Corollary:**

$$ | \sqrt{ z^2 + a }  - z | \leq \frac{a} { | \sqrt{z^2 + a } + z| } \leq \frac{a}{|z|} $$

Comment: Thank you sir, but what about the case z is real negative?. This inequality will be false. Have we precise the Damaine of z ?

Comment: Note that $ |z| > n$, where $n$ is large enough and has to be determined. This is what makes the inequality true (IE The cases where it's false, have a small $|z|$ value.) Roughly (handwaving) speaking, if $|z|$ is very large compared to $a$, then $ \sqrt{ z^2 + a } \approx z$ and so $ | \sqrt{ z^ 2 + a } + z | \approx 2z$. We  are then allowing for (more than) enough of a buffer.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kindness. Does this still true if we take $z=x<0$. I think that the inequality will be false. Must we specify the domain?